# Microsoft Web Deployment Service Silent Install

Tags: msi, msdeploy

I am trying to script the installation of the web deployment service (WebDeploy_x64_en-US). 
There is a quiet flag (/quiet), however it does not install the remote management service by default.
I did a "WebDeploy_x64_en-US /?" but I can't see any command line argument for selecting features.

Does any one know how make to WebDeploy_x64_en-US.msi install all the features quietly?

Oscar

Answer (score 6):

I had to add LicenseAccepted="0" to get it to install.

```
msiexec /i c:\path\to\WebDeploy_x64_en-US.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn /norestart LicenseAccepted="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Silent install command line, with all features:

```
msiexec /i c:\path\to\WebDeploy_x64_en-US.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn /norestart
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  It just hangs.  I think it's because the EULA isn't automatically accepted.

Comment: @GregB I suspect you are right about the EULA. I have experienced something very similar recently with Windows SDK.

Comment: I posted an answer with the LicenseAccepted parameter.

Comment: So in a build setting how would i know when the install is done to move on to the next step of the build?

Comment: In addition to comment question before this, i had the directory path wrong for the silent install but didn't see any indication in event viewer or anywhere that it was wrong. I just happen to take a 2nd look and notice it.